# Android App: When app signs in a black bar blinks and goes down my app

Tags: android, kotlin

When a user signs in on my app a black bar blinks and goes down my app.

It looks awful. When the user successfully logs in on the application a horrible black bar blinks at the top where the time and battery power is and then shoots down the screen. It only happens for about 2 seconds but it just looks awful and makes my eyes hurt, haha!

Is there any way to get rid of this? I have been trying so many different ways but I just have no idea.

It's only when I use the Google sign in (I have used the [integrate Google sign in tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating))

Any ideas would be helpful! Thank you all!

```
class LoginActivity() : AppCompatActivity(), GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    var RC_SIGN_IN: Int = 0
    lateinit var mSignInButton: TextView;
    lateinit var mMainLogoImage: ImageView;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        //Init Views
        mSignInButton = findViewById(R.id.loginTextView);
        mMainLogoImage = findViewById(R.id.mainLogoImage);

        val gso: GoogleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        val gac: GoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build()

        //Set the listener to the signin button
        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener {
            val signInIntent: Intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(gac)
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
        }

    }

    override fun onConnectionFailed(p0: ConnectionResult) {}

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val result: GoogleSignInResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
        handleSignInResult(result);
        }

    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(signInResult: GoogleSignInResult) {
        if(signInResult.isSuccess) {

            // val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            //startActivity(intent)

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to log in, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }

}
```

[image: GIF of a black bar shown when the login button is clicked]

Comment: Attach a gif and some code please.

Comment: Hi Divergence, I've done that and edited my post :-)

Comment: Eww... That does look kinda gross. Any ideas to whats happening? Is the login dialog coming down from above?

Comment: No, the login dialog comes up really nice in the middle of the app, this is when the login is successful (and it happens before I try and move onto my next activity) (on the gif it is auto login that's why it's not showing the login box) I literally have just used the code from the tutorial too, nothing extra.. it's so annoying.

Comment: have you tried it one a real/different AVD device? Try deploying on a device with a different API level and screen size/density

Comment: Yeah tried it on multiple devices, same thing.

Comment: I’m pretty sure the black bars are intentional - that activity would show an account chooser dialog if you have more than one account. However, if you’ve logged in to the app or if you have only one Google account on your device, the activity would close itself, hence the black bar briefly shows.

Comment: So there is no way of getting rid of it? It just looks awful, even when I link it to move to the next activity it shows up, it just makes the app look horrid.